# Cross Apply Syntax error in SSMS 17.3, no error in SSMS 17.1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, cross-apply

I have the exact same query. Works on 17.1 version of SSMS, but not 17.3

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Orders

-- DDL and sample data for UNPIVOT Example 1
CREATE TABLE #Orders
(
     Orderid INT IDENTITY, 
     GiftCard INT, 
     TShirt INT, 
     Shipping INT  
)

INSERT INTO #Orders
    SELECT 1, NULL, 3 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 5, 4 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 3, 10

SELECT * FROM #Orders

SELECT 
    OrderID, ProductName, ProductQty
FROM 
    #Orders
CROSS APPLY 
    (VALUES ('GiftCard', GiftCard), ('TShirt', TShirt),
            ('Shipping', Shipping)) x (ProductName, ProductQty)
WHERE 
    ProductQty IS NOT NULL

DROP TABLE #Orders
```

This runs no problem on 17.1. If the same query is run on 17.3 the following error is returned

> Parse error at line: 16, column: 14: Incorrect syntax near '('

The only other different is the 17.3 version of SSMS is on a VM in Azure.

Otherwise they are exactly the same.

When I'm researching a reason, I'm getting 100% results for connectivity issues, which is not the case.

Comment: The SSMS version is irrelevant. The version of SQL Server you are connecting to is the important thing

Comment: Run `select @@version` on each version of SQL Server and post it here.

Comment: The version where the query works is `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)   Oct 20 2015 15:36:27   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) ` and the version where the query does not work is `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Nov 29 2017 09:37:51   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation `

Comment: Based on the comments then its the RTM SQL protocol probably does  not use `cross apply` the same way?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of SSMS is 17.4. For the best experience with SQL Azure Database while using SSMS please download and use only the latest version of SSMS. Please download SSMS 17.4 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) and do not use prior versions.

Additionally, temporary tables have a different behavior on Azure SQL Database as explained [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0013.htm).